# Refining Ticket Overflow

Tags: pokemon-rumble-rush

At the beginning of each day, the player can receive 3 Refining Tickets as a login bonus. On that same screen, it says that up to 10 Refining Tickets can be saved. However, if someone wanted to save up their Refining Tickets over 4 days, they would end up with 12 from their login bonuses.

What would happen to the other 2 Refining Tickets received, as only 10 can be saved? Are they lost forever or do they get temporarily stored until the user can receive them.

This also applies to a 5th or 6th day of login bonus tickets being received. Basically anything over the max of 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A player can only ever have the maximum number of tickets, which I've only ever seen as 10 but I suppose it could change or they may add a way to increase it.  If you log in with 9/10 tickets on the day you should receive 6, you will be given 1 to bring your total to 10/10.

I generally keep 4 tickets, and each day either use the 3 given on a yellow ore or if it's the 6 day, use all 10 on a purple.  You can spend single tickets to speed up the current ore refinement by 1 hour, so when I get 6 I generally spend 2 on a yellow or purple.